# How can I re-create a subscription via pglogical?

Tags: postgresql, pglogical

I am using `pglogical` in postgresql11 to replica data from master cluster to a slave cluster. It is working fine. but I run `pglogical.drop_subscription` to delete the subscription from `slave` instance. After that I tried to run `pglogical.create_subscription` to re-create the subscription, but the subscription status is `down` immediately.

When read the instance log, it has some errors about `duplicate key value violates unique constraint "Entity_pkey"`.  I think this error means there are many duplicate primary key data in the slave cluster. It is expected since the subscription worked before which leave many data in the database.

I don't have configuration for the setting `pglogical.conflict_resolution` which means it should use the default value `apply_remote`.

How can I re-create them without deleting these data from slave instance?